# SQL Server Express Jar File to work with Hibernate

Tags: database, hibernate, sql-server-express

In my application I want to connect SQL Server Express with Hibernate. But I don't know what is the jar file I need to download and where I get this jar file.
When I run my application without adding jar file then it is throwing error which is:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: JDBC Driver class not found: net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the JDBC driver for SQL Server [downloadable here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=11774).  Out of the three "download" buttons there, choose the last one for UNIX (Linux etc.) like OSes, or the middle one if your Hibernate runs on Windows.

Run or decompress; or tag your question with the appropriate OS if you don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

I get the answer and I am putting answer for this question so it will be helpful for others.

Download Driver [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21599)

**Class name:** com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver

**URL:** jdbc:sqlserver://server:port;DatabaseName=dbname

JDBC example:

```
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;DatabaseName=test", "sa", "password");
```